# Deadly and delicious

Tags: riddle

I could kill you
If you eat, not waste me
Yet my whole
Can be very tasty
A part of me
Can be used to entice
And if you've an adult mind
My whole can't be done twice

What am I?

Comment: -1 The last line is just bad taste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's

> <del>A cherry</del> A cherry pit

I could kill you
If you eat, not waste me

> <del>Cherry-bomb.</del> Per Josh' comments: apparently a cherry pit is poisonous.

Yet my whole
Can be very tasty

> Cherry the fruit

A part of me
Can be used to entice

> Knotting the stem with the tongue, is apparently considered attractive

And if you've an adult mind
My whole can't be done twice

> "Pop the cherry" idiom.

Comment: Go just a step deeper, and you get the point! It's not the cherry itself I'm looking for...

Comment: @Josh, you mean the seed? As in you can choke on it and die?

Comment: Actually, the pit is poisonous, and chewing on it can kill you. ;)

Comment: I made an new edit ;)

Comment: Excellent! You win the no-bell prize! The cherry pit being poisonous is something I learned just a couple of days ago. Apparently there are a few fruits with pits that can kill. Makes me want to rethink what I eat.

Comment: It's a myth. the hydrocyanid is not enough to kill a person. You would need to eat plenty to die. Have you ever eaten cherries from a glass? I mean when the pits are picked out first? Sometimes you will have a broken one in that bottle and I already ate some :)

Answer (score 2):

is it

> an apple?

I could kill you
If you eat, not waste me

> apple seeds contain tiny amount of cyanide

Yet my whole
Can be very tasty

> obviously the apple itself is tasty

A part of me
Can be used to entice

> something about the forbidden fruit

And if you've an adult mind
My whole can't be done twice

> forbidden fruit again I guess

Comment: You're on the right track - I didn't think of the Garden of Eden apple, but it doesn't quite fit the last couplet.

Answer (score 2):

Is it...

> False hope?

I could kill you
If you eat, not waste me

> Clinging to it can only consume you, better to nip it in the bud.

Yet my whole
Can be very tasty

> The comfort of illusion is usually much better than the harsh reality

A part of me
Can be used to entice

> As charlatans, mountebanks, politicians, grifters and swindlers of all shades know all too well.

And if you've an adult mind
My whole can't be done twice

> Because once you know, you cannot *un-know* without *conscious* self-deceit.

Comment: Way to think outside the box! However incorrect, this is still a very good answer, except it doesn't take an adult mind.